# How do I load sub array from Realtime Database using React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

There are records in real-time DB that have a subarray:
[image]

And I'm not sure how do I load it in my hook. I also created the type to receive it in an array.
I found some examples, however, I'm looking for a way to do it easier.

```js
type EventType = {
    id: string,
    autorID: string,
    autorNome: string,
    titulo: string,
    categoria: string,
    dateS: string,
    dateE: string,
    descricao: string,
    cancelado: string,
    confirmCount: number,
    confirmadosList: Record<string,{
        confirmedByUserID: string,
        confirmedByUserName: string,
        confirmedByUserAvatar: string
    }>
}

useEffect(()=>{
        const eventRef = database.ref(`eventos/${eventID}`)

        eventRef.once('value', evento =>{
            //console.log(evento.val());
            const eventValue = evento.val();

            const vari:EventType = {
                id: eventValue.key,
                autorID: eventValue.authorID,
                autorNome: eventValue.authorName,
                titulo: eventValue.title,
                categoria: eventValue.category,
                dateS: eventValue.startDate,
                dateE: eventValue.endDate,
                descricao: eventValue.description,
                cancelado: eventValue.canceled,
                confirmCount: eventValue.confirmados.length,
                confirmadosList: {
                    
                }
            }

            setEvento(vari)
            
            //setCountConfirm(Object.values(eventValue.confirmados ?? {}).length)
            //setHasConfirm(Object.values(eventValue.confirmados ?? {}).some(confirmado => confirmado.confirmedByUserID === user?.id))
        })
    },[eventID])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `confirmados` node in your database is a `Map`, not a list. While you can get just the values of the keys under `confirmados`, that means you're throwing away the keys themselves.

If that is what you want, it'd be:

```
eventRef.once('value', snapshot =>{
  ...
  const confirmadosValues = [];
  snapshot.child('confirmados').forEach((confirmado) => {
    confirmadosValues.push(confirmadosValues.val());
  });
  ...
```

If you only want the value of `confirmedByUserID`, that inner line would be:

```
confirmadosValues.push(confirmadosValues.val().confirmedByUserID);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm wondering to get both, the 'Eventos' node info and 'confirmados' node info.

Comment: Didn't the rest of your code work yet? Is `eventValue` not what you need for the rest of the data? If not, what value does it have?

Comment: The first part where I take the first node below of 'Evento' that does work, what is not working is the part that I try to take the 'confirmados' node. I'm wondering to take them in the same query (if not possible, then I have ideas about how to get it in another query, however, I would like to see if is there any possibility to take the data on the same query).

Comment: My code takes the `confirmados` from the read operation you already had. What didn't work about it when you tried my code?

Comment: Doesn't work on that way

Comment: I'm trying by:
`const firebaseConfirmados:Confirmados = eventValue.confirmados ?? {}

            const parsedConfirmados = Object.entries(firebaseConfirmados).map( ([key, value])=>{
                return {
                    id: key,
                    confirmedByUserID: value.confirmedByUserID,
                    confirmedByUserName: value.confirmedByUserName,
                    confirmedByUserAvatar: value.confirmedByUserAvatar
                }
            })`
but getting the error: ` is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Confirmados[]>`